# how can i get the desired font family in css?

Tags: html, css

i want to know the font family of
 [this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIBrG.png) but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to https://www.fontsquirrel.com and from there you can easily upload the image. It will automatically detect the font and you will have your result. 
I tried to search with your image. And here is your result https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator?token=lrndi30t54167e33

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to find out what the font is. The font is most likely Nimbus Roman CHS Bold by URW Global

Comment: how will i able to make my text into Nimbus Roman CHS Bold in CSS. I tries this- `font-family: Nimbus Roman CHS Bold;` but did not work out.

Comment: Did you install the font and specify the location inside your css?